# How to find all solutions to $\cos(x) = a$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inverse-trigonometric-functions

I have the following question at hand:

Find all extrema of the function $f(x) = x - 2\sin(x+ \frac{\pi}{4})$. That amounts to solving $\cos(x + \frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{1}{2}$. But simply using $\arccos(0.5) - \frac{\pi}{4}$ yields only one solution; I need all of them. How can I find them? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: draw the graph. What fundamental property of the sine and cosine functions do you also need?

Comment: @SeanRoberson well the derivative is -2cos(x + pi/4) + 1. Would be easy enough to find a set of its roots if it weren't for the +1

Comment: Forget about the calculus for the moment. Suppose we just graph $y = \cos x.$ What do you observe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inverse trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Solutions_to_elementary_trigonometric_equations)

Comment: @SeanRoberson well the roots seem to be at 1/2*pi + k*pi, and the extrema at k*pi, with k being any integer.

Comment: @peterwhy maybe it should, but I'm not very good at these kinds of trigonometric witchy woos so I can't really make sense of it.

Comment: Your question asks about $\cos(x) = a$, and the linked table has the solutions for $\cos\theta = x$.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I found a solution: Because the first two solutions are $\pm arccos(0.5) 
- \frac{\pi}{4}$, the period $2\pi$ dictates all the other ones:

$\frac{\pi}{12} + 2k\pi$ and $-\frac{7\pi}{12} + 2k\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Both the sine and cosine functions are periodic, with period $2\pi.$ This is usually seen in a first course in precalculus or trigonometry.

Take the unit circle (the circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin). A point on the circumference of the circle has coordinates $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle measured from the positive $x$-axis in the counterclockwise direction. If you start at any point and do one full rotation, you will return to that point. Recall that one full rotation is $2\pi$ radians.

Now suppose we draw a vertical line that intersects the circle twice. The angle formed by the center and the two points of intersection is a right angle - $\pi$ radians. So if we need to solve $\cos x = a$, what do we do? Take two cases, and account for periodicity.

A simple example - all solutions to $\cos x = \frac{1}{2}$ are angles of the form $\frac{\pi}{3} + 2\pi k$ and $-\frac{\pi}{3} + 2\pi k$ for integers $k$. Why? The principal range of the arccosine function is the interval $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}.$ This is to ensure we actually have an inverse function.

Now you can apply this reasoning to $\cos \left( x + \frac{\pi}{4} \right) = \frac{1}{2}$ by taking two cases, and subtracting from the "representative" angles I've given above. See chapters 5-7 of [OpenStax Precalculus](https://openstax.org/details/books/precalculus-2e) for more.

Comment: The principal range of the arccosine function is (usually) $0\le x \le \pi$. No $x$ in your $-\frac\pi2 \le x \le \frac\pi2$ would give $\cos x = -1$.